# New property needsInputModeSwitchKey in iOS11

Tags: ios-keyboard-extension, ios11

On What's New in iOS11 page, I found that 'Added needsInputModeSwitchKey, a property of UIInputViewController to control the display of the input-mode switch key'.The new property needsInputModeSwitchKey is readonly. I have developed a keyboard Extension via Swift, but I have no idea about this new property. Can someone give some advice. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by myself. While all input mothod is removed except a 3rd. There will be only one input method can be switched to. In this situation，the needsInputModeSwitchKey is false, and the switch key should be hide from 3rd keyboard extension.

Comment: I think we can also use this key for "Global keyboard change button" in iPhone X,
In iPhone X this property always returns false because there is no need to display "Global keyboard change button" in it. iOS already put it below the custom keyboard.

Comment: @Amit Bhavsar YES. But there might be a bug. Once an app doesn't make iPhone X adaptation and is build by Xcode 8.x or before, ‘ needsInputModeSwitchKey’  is false and the bottom is covered with black area in iPhone X. In this situation, if we don't display  'Global keyboard change button' in our keyboard extension area, it would be no button to switch.

Comment: @Tanddd How did you solve the situation you described? Not optimized apps need the globe button while the needsInputModeSwitchKey returns false.

Comment: The bug you've encountered is resolved in iOS 12 beta 1 btw :)